# JACK does not start from the Studio app after Ubuntu Studio 21.04->21.10

Tags: ubuntu-studio, jack

I upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 21.04 to 21.10, and now the Studio Control app can't start JACK. I have a Behringer UMC 1820 interface, and I've been also using a Native Instruments Audio 2 DJ interface while on the go (I'm on an Elitedesk 65W Mini).

From Qjackctl things start fine, but even while JACK is running, the Studio Controls app shows JACK status as unknown. It seems a bit fishy that even while the Audio 2 DJ is not connected, it's the only option available in the "JACK Master Device" pulldown menu. Similarily in the "USB device that should be Master" menu that option shown is the only one.

For what it's worth, also the Audio 2 DJ works through Qjackctl when plugged in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7vGp.png

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *Are you sure you upgraded to 20.10?  as it isn't possible using Ubuntu tools after a release reaches EOL - I'd check your details*

Comment: Also did you read release notes; Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS was the last release using Xfce, and thus it was warned not to upgrade it without risk of breaking your system... ie. re-install was mandated past 20.04 due to change in desktop.   https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/10/ubuntu-studio-20-10-released/   (*FYI: the same breaking applies to any release past 20.04; re-install is required*)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's 21.10 of course to which upgraded, as instructed on the Ubuntu Studio site. I'm trying to find the logs now to see why Studio Controls can't seem to work at all with JACK.

Comment: Please correct your question then, as currently written it's off-topic and has off-topic/close strikes against it. Rather than comment on your wrong detail; it's the question that is read (comments can be erased by the system to *clean* questions so details in comments are not treated as factual if the contradict). Comments are where we ask you questions, not for your replies as you're intended to correct/amend your question). Your question says multiple times you're on off-topic 20.10